# UIAlertView if not enough points (cocos2d iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, int, uialertview

I want a UIAlertView to popup if the user doesn't have enough points to purchase an upgrade. So far I have this code to spend points to get the upgrade. If the upgrade costs 300 points, and the user only has 150, I would like the UIAlertView to calculate the amount needed and say something like, "Sorry, you need 150 more points to buy this upgrade". Here's my code. ('mag' and 'score' are both ints.)

```
    -(int)mag {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kMagDefaultsKey];
}

    -(int)score {
        return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:kScoreDefaultsKey];
    }   
    -(void)setMag:(int)value {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:value forKey:kMagDefaultsKey];
    }
    -(void)setScore:(int)value {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:value forKey:kScoreDefaultsKey];
    }
    -(void)plusFiveMag:(id)sender {
        self.mag = self.mag + 5;
        self.score = self.score - 300;
    }
```

Comment: what is mean by mag and score explain it?

Comment: Mag is the upgrade, and score is the points/cost of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try somethin like this...

```
  -(void)alertview
    {
    if(self.Mag>self.cost)
    {
    int difference;
    difference=self.Mag-self.cost;
    UIAlertView *Alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"your message" message:differene delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

            [Alert show];
            [Alert release];

}
}
```

Comment: That would work. But why add label to alert view? Just show the difference as a message in the alert?

Comment: I have 3 seperate "Upgrade" classes within a class called "Upgrade". Can I put that method in the original class "Upgrade" and have it function for all "Upgrade" classes? How?

Comment: Also, if you set the message to 'difference', wouldn't the only thing there say the #? How can I make it so it says "You need 'difference' more points"?

Comment: @Joethemonkey101: Try something like this for your message .... `message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Sorry, You need %i more points to be able to purchase this upgrade", difference]`